# How to start Outlook Office 365 automatically with Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365

All answers to this question that I found so far boil down to the assumption Outlook is installed in a static location. With the Office 365 pc installation, it is not so static.

Currently Outlook is installed in the path `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Office.Desktop.Outlook_16051.11727.20244.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Office16`. This path changes with each update, and it looks like it even changes with each restart. Which means I can't simply start Outlook.exe on startup from a file location.

Also there is no 'Open file location' option when right clicking the application in the task bar or the icon in the start menu when I search for 'Outlook'.

I could create a powershell script or batch file which would simply call 'Outlook' because that command still works. But I'm look for a build in solution. Am I missing a setting?

What I tried:

- Start outlook from the path it is located, fails at reboot
- Could not find it in the Start Up list in the settings
- Browsed through the settings of Outlook but could not find it

I installed the Office app, bought a 365 license and installed Outlook (among others) from there.

Update:
As I said, I could create a simple batch script to the start outlook. But if I were to help others with the same problem, or try to fix this in a office with multiple people, a batch script is not ideal because it requires a lot of explaining.

What I'm looking for is a non-technical solution. Such as a setting, a three-clicks away option, or maybe even a "Restart the installation and check this box during installation". If there is none, I'm obviously stuck with the script, but I would like to know if there are any other options I missed.

Comment: is Outlook.exe not in your "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\VERSION" folder? You could also move that batch containing `start outlook.exe` to your Startup folder, or create a scheduled task to launch outlook.exe when you log in - I'll just go ahead and put it in an answer, actually..

Comment: updated my answer with more of the stuff you likely don't want to hear

Comment: @mael' thanks for the effort and the elaborate answer. I guess there is no other way then :(...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If outlook.exe is not in your `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\OFFICEVERSION` folder, can you confirm if `start outlook.exe` launches the program?

If so, you can add this batch file to `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`:

```
@echo off

start outlook.exe

exit
```

or create a Scheduled Task that `Triggers at logon`, with the action to start the script `start outlook.exe`.

---

**Update:**
Unfortunately, any solution involving a user doing something on a computer is technically going to be.. technical (even if people are more comfortable with pure GUI - at the end of the day they are just navigating somewhere and clicking something) - and the best way to deploy this is going to depend on the environment you're working in. I certainly understand the frustration with there not simply being a "Start Outlook Automatically" option for Outlook like OneDrive has, but at the end of the day - even enabling that OneDrive setting is just adding/modifying an entry in your Scheduled Tasks library. I believe limiting your approach on this is doing a disservice to yourself and the people you are trying to help, so you may want to also consider different ways of accomplishing the outcome that require little or not input from users; and I'm not sure what your work situation is where you would need to explain what a batch file is (beyond "it just launches Outlook automatically") when all you need people to do is run it.

### 1. Simple Instructions via E-mail

> - Send everyone the batch file as text (or just get a batch creatively through your mail filters)
> - Have them change the file extension or unzip as necessary
> - Have them drag and drop the file to their startup

This is two or three steps that if explained correctly, most people can follow (pictures always help).

### 2. Remote Options

If you're on a network and things are configured for you to have remote access to user machines, you can simply drag and drop the batch file into their startup folder, import a pre-configured task (.xml) into their user profile via command, push a scheduled task through GPO, or any of the other various methods of accomplishing this on their machines without have to go to each one and do the two required steps.

### 3. Automate

You can use a self extracting archive executable to zip the batch up and unpack itself into the startup folder when a user double-clicks on it, or you can have another batch file for them to double-click that would do something like this:

```
@echo off

set "strt=%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"

if not exist "%strt%\outlook.bat" (
    echo @echo off
    echo start outlook.exe
    echo exit
)>"%strt%\outlook.bat"
```

and either send it to them or host it on a file share they have access to; the same can be done with importing a task .xml file on the share - they would just double-click a batch file that imports it using `schtasks`.

There is no "cleaner" way to do it - Scheduled Tasks and the Startup folder are the main mechanisms for accomplishing this for most of the Office Suite - I would imagine to decrease startup issues and conflicts with AV software. There is likely a registry solution as well, but if we're not trying to get anymore technical it's safe to say we can avoid exploring that as an option.

Comment: As I said, I can create a powershell or batch script to automatically start it. But it seems rather silly that an office program cannot be started automatically in the OS of the same company.

Comment: There is no such location as "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\..."

Comment: 'Outlook' would suffice as a script, you can remove all other content. The batch file would automatically close, and Outlook is a standard command, just like 'Excel' and 'WinWord'.

Comment: how much more "built-in" are you looking for if putting something in your startup folder isn't good enough? also, if you type `outlook` into a batch file and run it, it's not going to do anything.

Comment: It is a rather technicaly solution, not every office user can create batch scripts, no matter how simple.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid - Even a scheduled task would require a script that starts an application.  It isn't clear what your limitations are and are not to be honest.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid you need to edit your question if you're looking for some sort of deployment or something - it says nothing about "every office user" accomplishing something. if the post was just to complain about Microsoft we can't help you - given your situation (the path being unreliable) - the methods I mentioned work with your circumstances to make Outlook launch at startup.

Comment: @mael' I'm just exploring solutions, not complaining. I'll try to clearify the question a bit.

Comment: @Ramhound see my update. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler way than creating a script.

For me, all my Office 365 App executables were in the `%localappdata%\Microsoft\WindowsApps` folder.

These are the steps then I took to have outlook run on startup:

1. Press `Win + R` to open the run menu.
2. Enter `%localappdata%\Microsoft\WindowsApps` in the text box and press the `OK` button.
3. Create a shortcut of `outlook.exe` by going to `Right-Click Menu > Send to > Desktop (create shortcut)`
4. Open the run menu again by pressing `Win + R` keys.
5. Input `shell:startup` in the text box and press the `OK` button to open my user's startup folder.
6. Cut and paste the shortcut I created earlier to the startup folder.

Microsoft should provide this option directly in Outlook but alas the world isn't perfect until you make it so.

Comment: There are no office apps for me in that folder :(. I hope the solution works for others though.